# didUpdateLocations not working in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, core-location

I am updating my app to Swift 3 and cannot get it to print out location coordinates.

I have Privacy - Location When In Use, Privacy - Location Always, and Privacy - Location Usage Descriptions in my info.plist file.

```
@IBAction func activateTestModeButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    print("Method called")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation){
        loadUser()
        loadCoreData()

        print("Updating location")

        let latitude:String = "\(newLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
        let longitude:String = "\(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)"

        print("Latitude = \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("Longitude = \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)")      }
```

It prints "Method Called" but nothing else. I also have the didFailWithError method included which I believe is required and it is not printing anything:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error){
    print("Location manager failed with error = \(error)")
}
```

Other pertinent code which one would assume I'd have:

```
/* Asking the user if we can access their location */
func Authorization(){
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        {
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("Authorized")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Authorized when in use")
        case .denied:
            displayAlertWithTitle("Not determined", message: "Location services are not allowed for this app")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not Determined")
            if let manager = self.locationManager
            {
                manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
        case .restricted:
            displayAlertWithTitle("Restricted", message: "Location services are not allowed for this app")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("Location services are not enabled")
    }
}

/* Location Detection */
func permission(){
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined
    {
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    Authorization()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager?.distanceFilter = 200
    self.locationManager?.delegate = self

}
```

Comment: Is `locationManager` `nil` when you try calling `startUpdatingLocation()` on it?

Comment: Also, the code you've shared where you call `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` implies that it could never be `nil`, but the code in `viewDidLoad` implies that `locationManager` is an Optional. Maybe you have a typo in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomend you to move the code that manages the Location to a class like this one. This code is from an app i made a few months ago, i tested it to see if it works and i does. So give it a try. You just need to create an object of this class. I left a commented print in the method `locationManager(:didupdate)`, you can uncomment it to see all the changes in you location.

I know it is not perfect but it got me the job done.

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class Location: CLLocationManager, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {
    private var latitude:Double
    private var longitud:Double
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
    override init() {
        self.latitude = 0.0
        self.longitud = 0.0
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        super.init()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            self.locationManager.delegate = self
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
    internal func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (manager.location?.coordinate)!
        //print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")

        self.latitude = locValue.latitude
        self.longitud = locValue.longitude
    }

    /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
    func getLatitude()->NSNumber{
        return self.latitude as NSNumber
    }

    /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
    func getLongitude()->NSNumber{
        return self.longitud as NSNumber
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be absolutely certain that the `CLLocationManager` instance, on which you're calling `startUpdatingLocation()` is not `nil`.

Also strange is that the code you've shared in `viewDidLoad` initializes the `locationManager` as an `Optional` property, however when you call `startUpdatingLocation()` its no longer an Optional? If that's right is that `IBAction` hooked up in some other ViewController? Or you haven't shared all the code in that `IBOutlet` that explicitly unwraps the `Optional`? Or maybe that is a typo?